# Find $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} na_n$ given that $0<a_0 <1$ and $a_{n+1}=a_n-a_n^2$ for $n\geq 0$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I understand that no matter what value $a_0$ takes on between $0$ and $1$ that $a_1\leq \frac{1}{2}$. This has lead me to believe that for all $n\geq 1$, $b_n=(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2})<a_n <\frac{1}{n}=c_n$. If this can be proven true, then it is easy to see, by the Squeeze/Sandwich Theorem that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}nb_n\leq\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}na_n\leq\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}nc_n$ and since $(nb_n)=(1-\frac{1}{n})\rightarrow1$ and $(nc_n)=(1)\rightarrow1$, then $(na_n)\rightarrow1$.

If I am completely off-base in these ideas, let me know too. Thanks.

Comment: $(\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n^2}) < a_n$ is false when $n=2$.  Take $a_0$ to be very small

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506723/find-asymptotic-of-recurrence-sequence