# Leading asymptotic term of the nonlinear first-order recurrence $a_n=a_{n-1}+\sqrt{a_{n-1}}$

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relations, recursion

I have a nonlinear first-order recurrence of the form
$$
a_n=a_{n-1}+\sqrt{a_{n-1}},
$$
with $a_1=b>0$.  While simple in form, I suspect there is no closed-form due to the nonlinear square root term.  However, the asymptotics of the recursion are of interest to me.

Playing around with different values of $b$ I (apparently) discovered for large $n$
$$
a_n\sim Cn^2.
$$
But why is this?

Larger values of $b$ ($b\geq 1$) show quicker convergence to the quadratic form as compared to $b<1$.

Here is a plot of $a_n/n^2$ vs. $n$ for $b=1$:
[image]

Also, here is a table of the first several $a_n$ when $b=1$:

$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & a_n\\
 1 & 1 \\
 2 & 2 \\
 3 & 2+\sqrt{2} \\
 4 & 2+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}} \\
 5 &
   2+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}}+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{2+\sqrt{2}
   }} \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1196979/42969

Comment: Heuristically, $a_n-a_{n-1}=\frac{da_{n-1}}{dn}\cdot1+\frac12\frac{d^2a_{n-1}}{dn^2}\cdot1+...=\sqrt {a_{n-1}}$.  Supposing that at $n\to\infty\quad\frac{da_{n-1}}{dn}\gg\frac{d^2a_{n-1}}{dn^2}\gg...\quad\Rightarrow\quad\frac{da_{n-1}}{dn}\approx\sqrt {a_{n-1}}\,\Rightarrow\,a_{n-1}=\frac14n^2+o(n^2)$. The condition $\frac{da_{n-1}}{dn}\gg\frac{d^2a_{n-1}}{dn^2}$ is met.

Comment: It seems that $\,a_{n-1}=\frac{n^2}2-\frac{n\ln n}{4}+Cn+o(n);\,n\gg1\,$, where the constant $C$ depends on $a_1$

Comment: @Svyatoslav How did you come to that result?

Comment: Sorry, corrected a typo: should be $\,a_{n-1}=\frac{n^2}{\color{red}{4}}-\frac{n\ln n}{4}+Cn+o(n);\,n\gg1\,$, where the constant $C$ depends on $a_1$.
Step by step iterations: $a_{n-1}=a^0_{n-1}+a^1_{n-1}+...$, where (we suppose) $a^0_{n-1}\gg a^1_{n-1}\gg...$. Then we get $\frac{d(a^0_{n-1}+a^1_{n-1})}{dn}+\frac12\frac{d^2a^0_{n-1}}{dn^2}\approx\sqrt{a^0_{n-1}+a^1_{n-1}}\approx \frac n2+\frac{a^1_{n-1}}n$. Searching for $a^1_{n-1}=bn+cn\ln n\,\Rightarrow\, c=-\frac14$, and $b$ cannot be found from the equation.

Comment: $\frac{a_n-a_{n-1}}{n-(n-1)} = \sqrt{a_{n-1}}$ or $a_n'=\sqrt{a_n}$ or $a_n = 4n^2+C$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aproximation of $a_n$ where $a_{n+1}=a_n+\sqrt {a_n}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196979/aproximation-of-a-n-where-a-n1-a-n-sqrt-a-n). My answer is very precise and is for general $a_1>0.$