# Find the formula for the general term of the sequence giving by the recurrence

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations

How I should deal with it? 
I’ve tried so far to find an obvious pattern finding some terms of the sequence.

$$x_{n+1}=x_n - x_{n}^2$$
$$x_0=\frac 12$$

Comment: What's the initial condition? That matters

Comment: Also, what did you try?

Comment: $x_0\in\Bbb R$ doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: What is the source of the problem ? You seem to be missing an important detail.

Comment: How do you know there is a closed formula for it?

Comment: $x_n=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$ if $x_0=\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @Tuvasbien how do you came up with that result?

Comment: @Tuvasbien I get $x_2 = \frac{3}{16}$ not $\frac1{8}$

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit yah I got the same thing, but once again it doesn’t solve my problem.

Comment: By calculating the first terms, you can easily see the pattern, but I think $0,\frac{1}{2}$ and $1$ are the only values of $x_0$ for which there exists an easy formula for $x_n$.

Comment: @Tuvasbien $x_n=1/2^{n+1}$ doesn't seem correct

Comment: You're right, calculus errors.

Comment: Despite getting an explicit formula, one can show that $x_n\sim\frac{1}{n}$ for all $x_0\in]0,1[$.

Comment: The earliest appearance of this sequence in MSE seems to be [MSE question 506723](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/506723) "Find asymptotic of recurrence sequence". Later appearances include questions 517099, 1558592, 2471982, 2861768, 3088856, 3338930.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find asymptotic of recurrence sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/506723/find-asymptotic-of-recurrence-sequence)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no formula for the general term of the recurrence $\,x_{n+1}=x_n-x_n^2\,$
however, there is some specific results about
the sequence with $\,x_0=1/2.\,$
The denominator of $\,x_n\,$ is $\,2^{2^n}.\,$
[OEIS sequence A076628](https://oeis.org/A076628)
is the sequence of numerators of $\,x_n\,$
where $\,x_0=\frac12,\, x_1=\frac14,\, 
x_2=\frac3{16},\,x_3=\frac{39}{256},\, 
x_4=\frac{8463}{65536},\,\dots.$

In 1999 I found the result (where the constant $c$ depends on $x_0$)
$$x_n =1/( n + c + \log(n + c-1/2 + \log( \\
n + c-17/24 + \log(n + c-919/1152 + \dots )))). \tag{1}$$
With $y_n:=1/x_n$ and $L_n:=\log(n)$, then $y_{n+1}=y_n^2/(y_n-1).\;$
The general result is
$$ y_n = n + (c_0+c_1L_n) + (c_2+c_3L_n)/n + \\(c_4+c_5L_n+c_6L_n^2)/n^2 + \dots \tag{2}$$
for some constants $c_0,c_1,c_2,\dots$ which depend on $x_0$.
Now first replace $n$ with $n+1$ in $y_n$ to get
$$ y_{n+1}\!=\!n\!+\!(1\!+\!c_0\!+\!c_1L_n)\!+\!(c_1\!+\!c_2\!+\!c_3L_n)/n
\!+\!(c_4\!+\!c_3\!-\!c_2\!-\!c_1/2\!+\!(c_5\!-\!c_3)L_n\!+\!c_6L_n^2)/n^2 \!+\!\dots \tag{3}$$
while using the recursion gives
$$y_{n+1}\!=\!n\!+\!(1\!+\!c_0\!+\!c_1L_n)\!+\!(1\!+\!c_2\!+\!c_3L_n)/n
\!+\!(c_4\!-\!c_0\!+\!1\!+\!(c_5\!-\!c_1)L_n\!+\!c_6L_n^2)/n^2
\!+\!\dots \tag{4}$$
and equating the two expressions for $y_{n+1}$ we must have
$$c_1=c_3=1,c_2=c_0-1/2,c_5=3/2-c_0,c_6=-1/2,c_4=(-5+9c_0-3c_0^2)/6. \tag{5}$$
Making the substitutions for the constants we get
$$y_n\!=\!n\!+\!(c_0\!+\!L_n)\!+\!(c_0\!-\!1/2\!+\!L_n)/n\!
+\!((-5\!+\!9c_0\!-\!3c_0^2)/6+(3/2-c_0)L_n\!-\!1/2L_n^2)/n^2+\dots \tag{6}$$
and
$$x_n=1/n+(-c_0-\log n)/n^2+(c_0^2-c_0+1/2+ \\
(2c_0-1)\log n+(\log n)^2)/n^3+\dots \tag{7}$$
which still depends on $c_0$ which comes from $x_0$.

Comment: I decided to copy the contents of this answer to answer essentially the same question at [MSE question 506723](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/506723).